# Working with multiple date axes in ChartJS

Tags: chart.js

I'm trying to setup a chart with 2 datasets, 1 as a line which will show a median value for a month, and 1 dataset as a scatterplot which shows the value on a certain day. The daily date doesn't need to be shown on the x axis.

I'm using dayjs as my time formatting library elsewhere within my app so I was trying to use the [chartjs-adapter-dayjs-3 library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-adapter-dayjs-3).

I'm happy to manage the construction of the x,y objects myself for the data.

I've set up a [codepen](https://codepen.io/rowanwins/pen/ExvLKVX?editors=1111) showing what I think should work but I'm just getting a blank chart at the moment so I'm obviously doing something wrong.

```
import dayjs from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/dayjs@1.10.7";
import * as chartjsAdapterDayjs from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/chartjs-adapter-dayjs@1.0.0";


const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
const today = dayjs()

const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  data: {
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Median Sales",
        data: [
          {x: today, y: 10},
          {x: today.add(1, 'month'), y: 20}, 
          {x: today.add(2, 'month') , y: 15}
        ],
        type: "line",
        xAxisID: 'x1'
      },
      {
          label: 'Individual Sales Prices',
          data: [{x: today, y: 8}],
          type: 'scatter',
          xAxisID: 'x2'
        }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x1: {
        type: 'time',
        time: {
           unit: 'month'
        }
      },
      x2: {
        type: 'time',
        time: {
           unit: 'day'
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

I'm finding it a little unclear as to how time-based data, and axes ought work at the moment so any help would be appreciated.

**Desired Layout**

[image: Example]

Comment: Even examples of how to achieve the desired layout with other data structures or date libraries would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are getting is because of 2 things. The first thing is that you are not using the date adapter your say you are using. You are using another one and importing it with skypack which has the big side effect of also import Chart.js itself. The version of Chart.js that skypack imports is version 2.

The lib that you are linking does not seem to have a build available that works out of the blue in your browser even with their example using script tags. So if you want to use day.js you will need to write your own date adapter.

Example of just using js dates and using the date-fns date adapter:

```js
let start = new Date(),
  end = new Date();
start.setDate(start.getDate() - 7); // set to 'now' minus 7 days.
start.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); // set to midnight.

new Chart(document.getElementById("lastSevenDaysOverview"), {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Dataset 1',
        data: [{
          x: new Date('10-16-2021'),
          y: 1
        }, {
          x: new Date('10-18-2021'),
          y: 4
        }, {
          x: new Date('10-19-2021'),
          y: 66
        }],
        borderColor: '#ff3366',
        backgroundColor: '#ff3366',
      },
      {
        label: 'Dataset 2',
        data: [{
          x: new Date('10-16-2021'),
          y: 31
        }, {
          x: new Date('10-18-2021'),
          y: 14
        }, {
          x: new Date('10-19-2021'),
          y: 6
        }],
        borderColor: '#880000',
        backgroundColor: '#880000'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    interaction: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: true,
    },
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      y: {
        type: 'linear',
        display: true,
        position: 'left',
      },
      x: {
        type: "time",
        time: {
          unit: "day"
        }
      }
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<canvas id="lastSevenDaysOverview"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks @LeeLenalee , that example is almost perfect and shows me enough of the critical bits. I might look into writing and publishing a new dayjs adapter.